# Magento - Change translation don't work

Tags: magento, translation

I wan't to change the string:

```
$message = $this->__('There is already an account with this email address. If you are sure that it is your email address, <a href="%s">click here</a> to get your password and access your account.', $url);
```

located in the **core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php on line 345**

I've changed the translation (with Notepad++) in: **/design/frontend/default/my_theme/locale/de_DE/translation.csv** but it's not working. Anything else, translated in this file, is working fine.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Danny

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Translations are cached so you will need to clear the cache in *System > Cache Management* or by emptying the contents of `var/cache` directory.

Another way is to use the [inline translation tool](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/video-in-line-translations/) that is built into Magento.

Comment: Clearing the cache didn't work, but the inline translation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's a strange but trivial problem still in 1.9.2.1

Put the original string and the translated one (the complete translation line) into Mage_Customer.csv (instead Mage_Adminhtml.csv) in your preferred language pack folder and the translation will work.

Answer (score 0):

In `bin` folder run `php magento cache:flush` CLI command. That does the same thing in magento 2 from terminal as @clockworkgeek suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set locale option default on System->Configuration->General and on tab Locale Option set locale with your language translation