# Magento translation not working

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I've three store views : default, **de** for German and **fr** for French.
I've translated all the files inside **app\locale\en_US** in above two languages. 

 I've placed the respective translated file inside **de_DE**   `app\locale\de_DE` for german translation and **fr_FR** `app\locale\fr_FR` :  french translation.

Cleared the cache, still the it's translation is not reflecting.

I tried manually deleting cache from `var/cache` (**[this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857512/magento-change-translation-dont-work)**), but, is still not working.

Comment: Did you also set the locale in _System > Configuration > General_ for each store? (You probably have but didn't mention it and I can't think of anything else)

Comment: yes, it's set, for French, it's French (France) and for German it's German (Germany)...

Comment: this tripped me up. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Step by step :

1. Create two stores
2. Select Language for each store

   - Admin -> System -> Configuration
   - Select Store on top left corner listbox (current configuration scope).
   - Click General on left side bar
   - Select your language from "Locale Options" section.

Ps : Don't forget to save translated files with "UTF-8 Without BOM" option! ( if you aren't in China )

Comment: Doesn't help. Have default locales set per store, but translation files are not read. Sadly...